# which regression model: nested, censored data

Tags: r, regression, censoring, multilevel-analysis

I have the following data structures and would like to know your opinion which regression models are most suitable (and available in R)

model 1:
- 20,000 cases
- nested in 500 spatial units (only intercept variations are needed)
- the response variable is censored (only values >1) are possible
- 10 independent variables (only linear main effects are needed)

model 2:
- 20,000 cases
- nested in 500 spatial units (only intercept variations are needed)
- the response variable is categorized in 3 classes where class 1 < class 2 < class 3
- 10 independent variables (only linear main effects are needed)